# ASP core config files

Tags: asp.net, json, web-config, appsettings

In ASP framework I can add

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectStrings.secrets.config" />
```

to the Web.config file and have a local development database ConnectStrings.secrets.config file which is in the root folder of the project but not included in the solution, and a deployed ConnectStrings.secrets.config file with my live database details.

Its a great fail safe to only develop with the dev database and publish to staging and live environments without cross pollination.

I don't want to setup predicates etc, so wont use appsettings.development.json etc.  Is there a way of working with ASP Core and its appsettings.json file to refer to a separate file as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any binding redirects in the json config of ASP core.
Generally the way we handle something like this (which is not quite as great but helps solve the whoopsies) is to validate config on startup. Inside of each config file such as appSettings.development.json we have the following key

```
Environment: "Development"
```

If the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is a mismatch, prevent app from starting.